# How do I build a deb that is fully compatible with an offical deb?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, postgresql

I've downloaded the source of postgresql-9.3 by doing:

```
apt-get source postgresql-9.3
```

Then I've done my alteration to the configuration step and I've successfully built and tested the binaries. Now, I'm lost. What is the magic to generate the .deb file with the proper versioning and dependency graph?

Comment: How did you build them? By modifying `debian/rules` and running `dpkg-buildpackage`?

Comment: No, I haven't built it. That's the problem. I don't know how to build it.